# Issue with child comp javascript when dynamically loading nested component

Tags: javascript, laravel, dynamic, nested

I'm new in forum and new in Laravel development. I have the following problem. I try to load dynamically nested Livewire components from the parent Livewire componen like:

```
<div>
        @if ($caller==0)
            <livewire:comp1>
        @endif
        @if ($caller==1)
            <livewire:comp2 >
        @endif
    </div>
```

In the nested comp (day comp1) I have a vast js logic. As I work with statically nested components I always used

```
@push('scripts')
    <script>
        document.addEventListener("livewire:load", function(event) {
      //my js logic
```

and it always worked out. For the dynamically bound nested components it never works because the event livewire:load has been fired before dynamically binding I think. If I comment out the eventlistener "livewire:load" it throuws the error "Livewire.hook is not a function" (my nested js logic contains hooks). So how can I bind the js logic  (Livewire command like hooks included) for the dynamically loaded nested livewire component? Is there some other event I should listen to instead of livewire:load. Please give me a piece od advice.